# What is the setting to view the time part with date in Oracle PL/SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named AUDIT which saves all the modifications done on an account. There is a field AUDIT_DATE which contains the date on which a particular modification has been done. Now the problem is, in one of my colleagues Oracle PL/SQL developer, I can see the time as well as the date in the AUDIT_DATE column, but in my Oracle PL/SQL developer, I can't see the time part. So I believe some setting is not properly done in my Oracle PL/SQL developer and that's why I can't see the time part. I asked the colleague, but he has no clue about the discrepancy.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer as you've tagged it, or Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer? They are distinct things and you seem to be confusing them in the question...

Comment: @AlexPoole ITs Oracle Pl/SQL developer.

Comment: Oracle don't make a product called "PL/SQL Developer". [They do make one called "SQL Developer"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). But you might mean [this](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html). I've given the info for both in my answer though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to see dates with times shown as well without applying a format mask with `to_char()`, you need to change your [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html). Assuming you do mean Oracle SQL Developer, you can do this from Tools->Preferences, expand the Database section in the panel on the left, and select NLS:

[image]

At the moment `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-RR`, which would show today as `16-MAY-14`. To show the full date and time I might set it to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`. You might want to change the `NLS_TIMESTAMP` format as well.

PL/SQL Developer also has NLS options under Tools->Preferences:

[image]

You can see the available [format models in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A).

If you're writing code that will or may ever be executed by someone else, do not rely on implicit formatting using those parameters. They're fine for ad hoc queries in your own enclosed environment, but they may break in interesting ways when someone else - with different NLS settings - runs them. For anything except ad hoc queries you should really specify the mask, using `to_char(<column>, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` or whatever model is appropriate. This of course also means you get the right formatting for the column; if you have columns that only represent times then setting the session's format model and relying on that means you see all the `00:00:00` times, which is often just noise.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and IMHO should have been marked as the correct/accepted answer.

Comment: The available "format models in the documentation" link is broken.  Any idea where it is now?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - updated the links for 19c.