# DATETIME format set to YYYY:MM:DD in SQL but insert query runs on DD:MM:YYYY in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `DATETIME` set as 
`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");` in my `getDateTime()` method in my DTO class and this method returns a date with time. This is further used to create a CSV(Excel) file but when I run INSERT/UPDATE query in SQL developer, it throws an error if I use the format as `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM'`. For`DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM`it runs successfully. Also in some cases while creating CSV, the date field gets missed. I have also checked DB table and the format for `DATE` is set as `DATE` in there. Can anyone suggest the possible reason for

1. Error in SQL Dev while Updating/Inserting date as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`
2. What the DATE field's format should be in SQL if my code has format as above. Or DATE should work just fine.

We are using Oracle as RDBMS. For running queries we use SQL Developer.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL != SQL Server != Oracle

Comment: We are using Oracle as RDBMS. For running queries we use SQL Developer.

Comment: 1) show us your update/insert statements and error message(s). 2) DATE format is just fine if you don't need the time part

Comment: You use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, which says YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOURS:**MONTH** (month? Again?) >>> should be "mi", not "mm".

Comment: Just tag your questions with **the actual database product** you're using. Applying multiple irrelevant tags just confuses people and makes it less likely you'll get a helpful. timely answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your Tools => Preferences => Databases => NLS section in SQL Developer.  It nominates the default date format (amongst other things) that the tool will expect.  You can alter this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of misconceptions in the question:

> I have `DATETIME`

Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type - it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` both of which have a time component.

> set as  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

A `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) column does not have a format; Oracle stores `DATE` data types as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) (and similar for TIMESTAMP data types) and it is not until it is passed to a client program (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, Java, Python, etc) and that client program formats it according to whatever rules it has that the date gets a format.

The default string format for dates in SQL/Plus or SQL Developer is set by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. Other clients will typically have parameters that you can set for the default date format (if they don't also use the NLS settings). However, beware that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so it belongs to the user's session and multiple users can each have a different value for the parameter corresponding to how they have set it.

If you have overridden the default date format settings in the SQL Developer IDE then you can change it in ["Tools" > "Preferences" > "Database" > "NLS"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702143/1509264).

> For `DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM` it runs successfully.

The [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) `MM` (and `mm` as it is not case sensitive) is for month and `HH` is a 12-hour clock so you are specifying:

```
day:month:year hours-on-12-hour-clock:month
```

If you want to give a date a specific format then you will need to convert it to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

or if you want to convert a string to a date then use:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( your_string, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

> Also in some cases while creating CSV, the date field gets missed.

It probably is not missed - it is probably just `NULL` and gets formatted as an empty string.